# Problem with opencv on creating Android App with Kivy and Buildozer: libpython3.5m.so,libpython3.6m.so,libpython3.7m.so not found

Tags: java, python, android, kivy, buildozer

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64 bit for creating an Android App using kivy,opencv,keras,tensorflow and buildozer and the requirement is added in buildozer.spec as:

`requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,numpy,opencv,keras`

Python 3.6 is used for this project.

I am able to successfully build using buildozer but on running the app on android, the screen just flashes and close immediately.

On checking "adb logcat" I got the following error:

```
07-07 13:33:35.787  5379  5379 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/org.test.solvescan-KYbuSS1mbnWzVojWX6j2QA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.test.solvescan-KYbuSS1mbnWzVojWX6j2QA==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.test.solvescan-KYbuSS1mbnWzVojWX6j2QA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libpython3.5m.so"
07-07 13:33:35.787  5379  5379 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/org.test.solvescan-KYbuSS1mbnWzVojWX6j2QA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.test.solvescan-KYbuSS1mbnWzVojWX6j2QA==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.test.solvescan-KYbuSS1mbnWzVojWX6j2QA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libpython3.6m.so"
07-07 13:33:35.788  5379  5379 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/org.test.solvescan-KYbuSS1mbnWzVojWX6j2QA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.test.solvescan-KYbuSS1mbnWzVojWX6j2QA==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.test.solvescan-KYbuSS1mbnWzVojWX6j2QA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libpython3.7m.so"
```

On searching for similar file i could find "libpython3.8m.so" after buildozer build but other 3.7,3.5 or 3.6 is not present.

I was using Pychram for this project and environment was set to python 3.6. Even on my system python3 points to python3.6.

Any insight would be helpful

Comment: These aren't actually problems, your app is built with python 3.8 because that's the p4a default (and I wouldn't try changing it, certainly not to less than 3.7, but that's fine).

Comment: There's probably an actual error somewhere else in the logcat, try looking at all the lines containing the string "python"

Comment: on checking again, there are more errors.

Comment: 7-11 14:39:25.368 20920 20940 E OpenGLRenderer: Device claims wide gamut support, cannot find matching config, error = EGL_SUCCESS
07-11 14:39:26.681 20920 20957 E libEGL  : validate_display:167 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)